# IBM Worklight v6.0 - failed installing the Mobile Test Workbench plug-in

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have installed the Worklight Studio v6.0 onto my Eclipse. But when trying Test Workbench plug-in I get the following error during the installation.

My setup:

- Eclipse java EE IDE for Web Developers - Juno Service Release 1 Build id: 20120920-0800
- Worklight Studio v6.0.0.20130614-0631

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: IBM Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight 8.5.0.v20130607_1553 (com.ibm.rtw.extension.feature.feature.group 8.5.0.v20130607_1553)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (epp.package.jee 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    OSGi System Bundle 3.8.1.v20120830-144521 (org.eclipse.osgi 3.8.1.v20120830-144521)
    OSGi System Bundle 3.8.0.v20120529-1548 (org.eclipse.osgi 3.8.0.v20120529-1548)
    OSGi System Bundle 3.8.2.v20130124-134944 (org.eclipse.osgi 3.8.2.v20130124-134944)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Rational Test Workbench Mobile feature 1.1.0.v20130607_1327 (com.ibm.rational.test.lt.moeb.feature.feature.group 1.1.0.v20130607_1327)
    To: com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.runtime [1.1.0.v20130606_1642]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: RTW Mobile Android Runtime plugin 1.1.0.v20130606_1642 (com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.runtime 1.1.0.v20130606_1642)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.osgi 3.8.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight 8.5.0.v20130607_1553 (com.ibm.rtw.extension.feature.feature.group 8.5.0.v20130607_1553)
    To: com.ibm.rational.test.lt.moeb.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (epp.package.jee 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.5.1.20120917-1257]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse e4 Rich Client Platform 1.1.0.v20120521-2329-8yFTIGIbGGduEZ6-7-jLx41nXj (org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group 1.1.0.v20120521-2329-8yFTIGIbGGduEZ6-7-jLx41nXj)
    To: org.eclipse.osgi [3.8.1.v20120830-144521]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.5.1.20120917-1257 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.5.1.20120917-1257)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.2.1.v20120814-120134-7IAPA8BrHQicS-rjP0GbqK780kMy]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 4.2.1.v20120814-120134-7IAPA8BrHQicS-rjP0GbqK780kMy (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 4.2.1.v20120814-120134-7IAPA8BrHQicS-rjP0GbqK780kMy)
    To: org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group [1.1.0.v20120521-2329-8yFTIGIbGGduEZ6-7-jLx41nXj]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM Worklight v6.0 supports Eclipse Jave EE 4.2.**2** ("Juno" SR2) **only**.

Try removing the IBM Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight plug-in (in short: IMTWW), update to Eclipse 4.2.2 and then install the IMTWW plug-in again. See if this helps.

Comment: I used a different Eclipse SDK 4.2.2 and the installation of the mobile test workbench works.